# Why doesn't my Motorola G 5g 2022 camera focus

Tags: camera, motorola-moto-g

When I try taking a video, my camera does not focus on the subject. Although it is perfectly fine when taking pictures. Why is this and is it able to be fixed?

Comment: This may depend on the Camera app. Have you tried other 3rd-party Camera apps?